# css metro-ui not able to show focus on check-box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi i have a check box using metro-ui

```
<label class="text_blue small_text">
                <input name="enterprise_admin_session[remember_me]" type="hidden" value="0"><input tabindex="3" type="checkbox" value="1" name="enterprise_admin_session[remember_me]" id="enterprise_admin_session_remember_me">
                <span class="check border_radius_zero"></span> Keep me logged in </label>
```

when i use tab and focus on this check-box , i am not able to identify the checkbox is focused. Don't know what i am missing

Or if there is any way from `jquery`  to catch the focus event on the checkbox input and then change the css of `<span class ="check border_radius_zero"></span>`

Please help me to fix it, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what your problem is, but if you want to do it with jQuery here is an example of how you can do it.

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").focus(function(){
    var span_element = $(this).next("span.check.border_radius_zero");

    // Change background color
    span_element.css("background","red");

    // Or Toggle class
    span_element.toggleClass("className");

    // Or Whatever you want to do with that span
    span_element.DoWhateverYouWantWithMe();
});
```

If you need to discard that changes you made on focus, you can attach a `blur` event handler.

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").blur(function(){
    var span_element = $(this).next("span.check.border_radius_zero");

    // Change background color
    span_element.css("background","initial");

    // Or Toggle class
    span_element.toggleClass("className");

    // Or Whatever you want to do with that span
    span_element.UnDoWhateverYouWantWithMe();
});
```

I personaly prefer do it with a `class` so you can simplify the code, even use the same handler! For example, you can do this.

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").focus(function(){
    var span_element = $(this).next("span.check.border_radius_zero");
    span_element.addClass("className");
}).blur(function(){
    var span_element = $(this).next("span.check.border_radius_zero");
    span_element.removeClass("className");
});
```

With the same handler:

```
var focus_blur_event_handler = function(){
    var span_element = $(this).next("span.check.border_radius_zero");
    span_element.toggleClass("className");
}
$("input[type='checkbox']").bind("focus",focus_blur_eventHandler);
$("input[type='checkbox']").bind("blur",focus_blur_eventHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

No need of Javascript or Jquery. You can style using CSS by simply adding this to your stylesheet.

`input[type="checkbox"]:focus ~ .check{
    /*Your style goes here*/
}`

For reference, how to use general sibling selector(~) follow this link http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/general-sibling-selector-css-selector/

Here's the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/6a14tfd0/1/

```css
input[type="checkbox"]:focus ~ .check{
    color:red
}
```

```html
<label class="text_blue small_text">
                <input name="enterprise_admin_session[remember_me]" type="hidden" value="0">
                    <input tabindex="3" type="checkbox" value="1" name="enterprise_admin_session[remember_me]" id="enterprise_admin_session_remember_me">
                <span class="check border_radius_zero">***</span> | Keep me logged in </label>
```